# Dynamic search/filter core-list (Polymer 0.5)

Tags: polymer

I need to implement a filter-type search which hides items in core list if they do not match the search.  I created a .hidden class that is applied to an item if an expression returns false:

`class = {{ {hidden: !match(model.host, hQuery)} | tokenList }}`

The elements are hidden, but the list does not reflow elements unless I click on a visible row.  Is there a way to force a reflow using a function call?

[image: Blank]
[image: With Filter]
[image: After Click]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of struggling, hiding list items is just not the right way to handle this.  Iterate through the original array, push any matching objects to a temporary array, and then replace core-list's `.data` array with the temporary array: `this.$.list_id.data = tmpArray`.  Performance is good for lists up to 10K records.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing in my code, and it works:

```
 <div style="{{hide_part1}}">
 ...content to show/hide...
 </div>
 ....
```

Switching it based on route change(flatron-director):

```
  routeChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {

        if ('some_route_1' == this.route) {

            this.hide_part1        = ''
            this.hide_part2    = 'display: none;'

        } else if ('some_route_2' == this.route) {

            this.hide_part1        = 'display: none;'
            this.hide_part2    = ''
       }
   },
```

Also using core-list's updateSize() and especially scrollToItem(**0**), i.e. back to top, here and there helps as I also had problems with the 'reflow':
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29432700/polymer-core-list-is-not-rendering-some-of-the-elements

Comment: I tried invoking updateSize() on key-up, but it still seems to get out of sync.

Comment: I'm having trouble whenever the first matching item is outside of the current buffer.  `updateSize` and `scrollTo(0)` (scroll to top) do not help, I have to trigger a scroll to that specific index item.  I created (https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/87)[a Github ticket] but the best I can do for now is detect when the list might have more on the runway and then force a scroll to that specific item for each search entry.