# Bind to a core-list item's `hidden` attribute (Polymer 0.5)

Tags: polymer

Digging into the core-list source code, it looks like it checks an element's `hidden` attribute using Javascript. But setting `<div hidden="false">` results in the `div` being hidden.  Can I somehow bind an expression to this Javascript attribute or do I need to submit a PR to core-list to explicitly add support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide / show polymer elements with the hidden? attribute.

```
<span hidden?="{{showSpan}}">This may or may not be hidden.</span>
```

if the boolean expression 'showSpan' is truthy, the span element is displayed, otherwise it is omitted.

You can toggle the state of showSpan like this:

```
<div on-click="{{showinput}}">
   <span hidden?="{{showSpan}}">This may or may not be hidden</span>     
</div>



 Polymer({

       showSpan: false,

       showinput: function() {
         this.showSpan = !this.showSpan;
         }
     });
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but I'm not sure if this will work for items in core-list 0.8+ since I think they removed the ability to pass variables to expression binding.  Granted, this is what I asked for, but I don't think it will work long term.

Comment: @Indolering - According to the 0.8 docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/devguide/data-binding.html) this will still be possible. Personally, I'm holding off of playing with 0.8 until all the core-elements are ported.

Comment: I'm not so sure, they only show public attributes (not something like `{{record in records}}`) and the [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/migration.html) states, "No expression support. Binding is to properties or paths only."  Furthermore, I've come to find that [hiding items in core-list a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596127/dynamic-search-filter-core-list-polymer-0-5/29601499#29601499).

Answer (score 3):

If you want that your element not being hidden you should remove the hidden attribute. hidden="false" does not means much in html.